# Avoid return type "void" with type using enum subset

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type-safe API-SDK where different entities support different API endpoints. There is one enum which contains all possible entities. In the example below only 2 of 3 entities support posting. As long as I call the post-function with a known type, the type is resolved correctly. But when I loop over all the endpoints supporting post, I get an additional return type `void`, which I then can't pass on to other functions, that shouldn't allow passing `void`. Probably the example below explains it better. How can I remove the `void` return type from my post-function or replace it by `never`?

```ts
enum Entity {
    Person,
    Organization,
    Job,
}

interface Person {}
interface Organization {}

const entityEndpointsSupportingPost= [Entity.Person, Entity.Organization];

type EntityEndpointsSupportingPost = {
    [Entity.Person]: Person;
    [Entity.Organization]: Organization;
    [Entity.Job]: void;
}

async function postEntity<T extends keyof EntityEndpointsSupportingPost>(endpoint: T): Promise<EntityEndpointsSupportingPost[T]> {
    const result = await fetch(`api/${endpoint}`);

    return await result.json();
}

const person = Entity.Person;

// This is recognized as Promise<Person>
const postedPerson = postEntity(person);

for (const entity of entityEndpointsSupportingPost) {
    // This type is Promise<void | Person | Organization>
    const postedEntity = postEntity(entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, which could also be an answer I think. Does this work with `as const`, because the compiler then knows that only those values are to be expected at runtime? Because now I can also remove `Entity.Job` from `EntityEndpointsSupportingPost`.

Comment: And just for curiosity I would still be interested if I could teach the compiler that any other case should be `never` and not `void`

Comment: I'd need to see a [mre] of what you mean by "any other case" and that would ideally be in a new post instead of in the comments (or expanding the scope of the original question which I'm not prepared to deal with).  In theory you can wrap your offending type in `Exclude<⋯, void>`, but if you need more than that you should open a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here seems to be that the compiler is unaware that `entityEndpointsSupportingPost` does not actually contain `Entity.Job`.  That's because the type of `entityEndpointsSupportingPost` is inferred to be `Entity[]` based on the initializing array literal.  Such inference is heuristic in nature; the compiler assumes you may want to add or remove `Entity` elements from that array later.  But since you intend for it to be a permanent unchanging record of acceptable elements, you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) as a hint that you'd like a more specific type:

```
const entityEndpointsSupportingPost =
    [Entity.Person, Entity.Organization] as const;
```

// const entityEndpointsSupportingPost:
//   readonly [Entity.Person, Entity.Organization]

Now the compiler knows that `entityEndpointsSupportingPost` contains exactly the two elements it contains, and it also knows their order (although you don't care about that).

And then your code will work without as desired and without errors, because `entity` is of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `Entity.Person | Entity.Organization`, and thus `postEntity(entity)` is of type `Promise<Person | Organization>`:

```
for (const entity of entityEndpointsSupportingPost) {
    const postedEntity = postEntity(entity); // okay
    // const postedEntity: Promise<Person | Organization>
}
```

Furthermore, assuming you don't want to support `postEntity(Entity.Job)` at all, you should just remove it from `EntityEndpointsSupportingPost`, since there's no reason why it needs to be there anymore:

```
type EntityEndpointsSupportingPost = {
    [Entity.Person]: Person;
    [Entity.Organization]: Organization;
    // [Entity.Job]: void; // removed, unnecessary
}
```

And now you'll be warned if you call `postEntity` with an invalid input, prompting the user to fix their TS code so that it doesn't send the wrong thing to the API at runtime (since merely having a `Promise<void>` doesn't imply any sort of problem to the user):

```
postEntity(Entity.Job) // compiler error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAoiAuBLeBPKBvAsAKCnqACsAE4DOA9iADQ75QDyxA5gIYiIBeLSlNu+AKXIAjPgF8cORAhIAzFgGNghEhRAYoE7NPhzFyxq3Zce69JsnYFlUvCigkqOABMADuR2kAymFfviSCBMBOS2UAC8tPgA2nCOKAB0RGS8sAjIiYZsnNyIlAC6UCykUNYgtgDcUAD01VAAPAC0jVDwABaIpAD8lrWlNnYOGS7unj5+5AHSwaHwAFxQxMAszpQANmix6ahJqqlxGQlZxrkFlqiuygdOIG4eCN6+-oEzYeEYUXhb8bspIPkLZJqCqfKDfQ7HHKmAEMZjZEx5EAg-h4PrgnZCYQwgBuHmcVT6TRabGc1UmUAAVmAwksIORscp2p0oGtpMpyQo2mwmMpkD1sFocMUUCAFFBZGBRaYoO5bNcUPUACr2AAeuluJQA1sAUORZGl4iN7vBHhMpkEQrYAHwAClAdx0C0VAEpAcRyBBOsB6vKjWMnpMXpb4NFFfkrR8Uf1ynYlqQwGs7O8WAB3FjIcXAeCcm0AAxYrkQ1QAJOh7aMEGJc87kaClvAwMR1Kn07HgPHEwkKWobTWcIKrAMZXt1O95b9gb06oqOiVmUtrExjMBnEUSgR3Z7SN6gZQrTgymFZbpnLvRzLZvKbZc-n3sDhZOSbYfBts0Hr7G+-Q9xs9psHnUjOgXwvWwV3lCJQPgK8hlQGsajqchNRYFBQT6EDj3At83Q9L16jPKAAB9YSMKFEX3AUgA)